# Display columnar data with css display table-column

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have two products that I want to display in tabular form.

```
<div id="products">
  <div id="product_one">
    <div>
      id one
    </div>
    <div>
      name one
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="product_two">
    <div>
      id two
    </div>
    <div>
      name two
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and I want them to look like this:

```
| id one     | id two     |
| name one   | name two   |
```

More specifically, I want the rows to stay in line, as they would with a table e.g.

```
| id one is   | id two    |
| longer this |           |
| time        |           |
| name one    | name two  |
```

I was hoping there was a way to do this with display: table-column, but I can't find any decent docs on it. Am I destined to have to reformat the HTML, or is there a way to do this with good ol' CSS?

**--edit--**

From the comments, it seems like this is impossible without something extra. Is there a short javascript solution that will solve the problem?

Comment: This seems to be tabular data so why not use a table which is what it was designed for?

Comment: Tables are an option, but it's not data - it's for presentation. Hence why I thought I'd see if there was a purely css solution.

Comment: unfortunately there is no real way without formatting the html or using tables.

Comment: Something like this? : http://jsbin.com/osazob/edit#javascript,html,live

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/CYfED/1/ hope this helps to accomplish your goal.

Comment: That's displaying the products from left to right in a row - I'm hoping to display them top to bottom in a column.

Answer (score 0):

Using duplicate `id`s is a curse.

This will solve your problem :

```
#products { display: table-row; }

#product_one {
    display: table-cell;  
    border: 1px dashed #000000;
}​
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/KpMGu/)

Comment: Whoops - the duplicate ID was a mistake. Fixed now. That said, using a table-cell doesn't solve the problem. Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zaius/KpMGu/1/

Comment: hehe ! then no way :) you need to give width for `#products > div` http://jsfiddle.net/KpMGu/2/